# How to delete an android app cache using code from an ionic v4 project

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I am new to ionic. I recently developed an app using ionic v4 and have installed it on an android phone for testing. The app sends a lot of http request to a WEB API on azure. It works very well until the app cache gets to about 25mb, then it becomes extremely slow or stops working altogether until I manually clear the cache.

Please is there any way that I can delete the app cache automatically using code. Please any advice/solution would be very much appreciated.

I tried to install cordova-plugin-cache-clear but couldn't get it to work.

At the moment, I manually go into Android settings, Storage, Other apps and then my app to select the clear cache button. Please is there a way to do that in code so to avoid the manual process of clearing the cahe that builds up overtime.

Answer (score -1):

How about using ionic-cache ?

[Ionic cache service]
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-cache

Ionic cache service that can cache almost everything. It caches requests, observables, promises and classic data. It uses Ionic Storage so we support IndexedDB, SQLite (Cordova), WebSQL in this order. It can be used separatelety in Angular 2 application.